# Issues saving and reading struct from file

Tags: c, fopen

I am working on a homework assignment that deals with writing and reading binary data to a file. In this assignment, we need to write multiple structs to a file and then be able to read them back. Right now, I'm starting out small and am attempting to write a single struct to a file (this works). However, upon reading the data from the file, I can see that the value for my int has changed (some random value), while the string is as it should be. Why would I be running into such an issue??? Does it have something to do with the endianness of the machine? Are there any other options available to me that would allow me to write and read binary data successfully?

```
typedef struct
{
int number;
char name[256];
} header;

header hdr = {.number = 1000, .name = "Testing"};
FILE * ifp;
fp = fopen("FileName", "w");
fwrite(&hdr, sizeof(hdr), 1, fp);
fclose(fp);

FILE * ofp;
header newHdr;
ofp = fopen("FileName", "rb");
fread(&newHdr, sizeof(newHdr), 1, ofp);
fclose(ofp);

printf("number = %d \nname = %s\n", &newHdr.number, &newHdr.name);


number = 329346238
name = Testing

number = -6239872395
name = Testing
```

Comment: You "w", but then "rb" - perhaps try "wb" ? Also, ifp and ofp seem to be reversed from what most people would expect.

Comment: I don't think your `printf` is correct; by prefixing the printed variables with `&` you are printing the address of those variables instead of their value.

Comment: @CongXu You were right. It didn't even cross my mind that I was printing the address of the number... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are writing the file as Text but Reading the File as binary. Kindly perform the function with same attributes changing w and r